# Can I get CosmosDB graph to return edge details for vertex objects in query results?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Consider the following simple gremlin query: `g.V("some_id")`

When executed against my CosmosDB graph database from the "Data Explorer" tab of the Azure web UI, I get the following results:

```
[{
    "id": "some_id",
    "label": "some_type
    "type": "vertex",
    "outE": {
        "some_edge": [{
                "id": "75b3c6ff-efdf-4a88-8cf6-aa395ef28bf7",
                "inV": "another_id"
            },
            {
                "id": "f3703292-12b9-44bc-a16f-26bac75f3420",
                "inV": "yet_another_id"
            }
        ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "some_property": [{
            "id": "50bda5cb-08ab-4727-b212-5ba4e829db3e|organizationId",
            "value": "hi there"
        }]
    }
}]
```

---

When I execute the same exact query against the same exact database using the gremlin websocket endpoint, I get the following results:

```
[{
    "id": "some_id",
    "label": "some_type
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
        "some_property": [{
            "id": "50bda5cb-08ab-4727-b212-5ba4e829db3e|organizationId",
            "value": "hi there"
        }]
    }
}]
```

---

What happened to the edges (the "outE" JSON key)? Only the "properties" key is included, but man, I need those edges! How do I adjust the output format to include them?

Comment: I'm unsure of what the proper behavior is for CosmosDB, but generally speaking you should look to avoid returning an entire `Vertex` (i.e. with all properties/edges included) and only return the data you need and do so explicitly. Just as you would not do `SELECT * FROM table` in SQL, you should look to avoid that pattern in Gremlin.

Comment: @stephenmallette Thanks for your comment. It's interesting, because the official spec shows the "inE" and "outE" keys present on GraphSON result payloads: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/reference/#graphson-io-format
Not as full edge objects, but just pointers (ids). I think that's handy, and I hope it's possible to enable on CosmosDB!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is an artifact of the way that the data explorer shows and parses the data returned by the underlying engine.  Since the edges are not properties of the Vertexes I don't think that these should be included as part of the Vertex returned by the query.  If you want to return the vertex and the associated edges you can do that using a query like this which works in the gremlin console and via the driver:

```
g.V('some-id').as('b').bothE().as('e').select ('b', 'e')
```